# Cannot link/deploy/display android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info on my hardware device

Tags: android, android-resources, android-dialog, android-testing

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
```

The above code should create an alert-dialog with the drawable resource android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info.  This code works perfectly fine in an Android Virtual device, but it does *not* work when I do live testing with a real hardware device.

What happened to my icon, and why does it not show up when I deploy to my phone?

Comment: Really now ... does the same thing happen when you're testing on many devices? Or only against one?

Comment: So far, I did not notice this issue on any *virtual* device that I have tested on.  These virtual devices are usually 5.4 inch or smaller, and API level 8 to 17 (android 2.2 to 4.2.2).

Comment: This only happens on my phone.

Comment: try cleaning up the project, rebuild ... I guess you called `builder.create().show()`, right?

Comment: Yes, I do have calls to create and show and I recently tried a clean deploy.  Please note that I just replaced my resource pointer to something in my own resource folder (and no longer using android.R).  It seems like setIcon does not work on hardware for icons in android.R...